# Pergola post wobble

Tags: wood, patio, pergola

I'm busy putting up a pergola. Today I've added 2 of the four posts and they feel quite wobbly..
Will this change once I started putting the structure together?
Will knee bracing assist greatly with the wobbliness?
Or should I look at somehow improve on the footing?

(The will be another post left of the closest post and another in line with the left post)
(The existing beams are attached with rawl bolts to the wall)

Thanks in advance!

[image: Post][image]

Comment: You've got an 8 foot(?) lever balanced on a <1" spike. If that didn't wobble some, I'd be _shocked_!

Answer (score 1):

The wobble is normal. When you start adding the horizontal members thing will stiffen up.

Comment: Even better when the knee bracing is in place.